# MongoDB filter for secondary textbox with req.query.value undefined problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

i noticed with node, express and mongo driver if a req.query.x/y... is undefined it returns me invalid during a search! example:

```
//req.query.name
//req.query.email
//req.query.city

var search = req.query.search; //used in the main serch box
//used as secondary textbox filters
if(req.query.name){
 var name = req.query.name;
  }
 if(req.query.email){
 var email= req.query.email;
  }
 if(req.query.city){
 var city= req.query.city;
  }
```

during a search on multiple textboxes I would like to eliminate the if conditions as much as possible!

in .ejs

```
//textbox filter
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="text" name="email">
<input type="text" name="city">
```

in .js

```
collection.find({
$text: {$search: search},
    or:[{
     name:{$regex: '^'+name},
     email:{$regex: '^'+email},
     city:{$regex: '^'+city}}
       ]
 }).toArray(function.......
```

I simplified the code a lot to get to the point of the situation (but I don't think the problem concerns the `$and` or `$or` and their structure|position)! however if one of the search conditions is **undefined** I do not get the desired result,
I would like to understand if possible to **exclude** `city` or `name` or `email` in case there are no assigned values!
how could I do ?
i can't use `req.query` because it matches a **higher search box**. in a nutshell **these three boxes** would be **filtering** from a text `req.query.search`

I tried that but without success:

```
if(name == undefined ){
name ="";}
if(email == undefined{
email="";}
if(city==undefined){
city="";}
```

thanks to anyone who answers me

Comment: You can create the entire query _filter_ based upon the request query string values. For example similar to this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69367673/mongoose-find-function-is-there-a-value-for-in-which-would-be-true-no-matter-w/69370680#69370680

Answer (score 1):

You can create your filter object and then pass to it your properties based if they're undefined or not; you can try it this way:

```
const {
  search,
  name,
  email,
  city,
} = req.query;

const filter = {
  $text: { $search: search },
  $or: [],
};
if (name) filter.$or.push({ name: new RegExp(name, 'i') }); // The 'i' flag is just for example purpose, that's all
if (name) filter.$or.push({ email: new RegExp(email, 'i') }); // same here
if (name) filter.$or.push({ city: new RegExp(city, 'i') }); // same here

const result = await collection.find(filter);
```

PS: Your using $text keyword, I don't know if you added a text index to your Mongoose schema definition that lets you use the $text operator in your find queries to search all fields included in the text index. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/).

Comment: however it seems like a good method ... unfortunately it gives me back either the city or the sex, if both are entered eg: female, new york gives me only female or vice versa .. I think undefined gives him problems

Comment: another problem I can only use it with $ text .... if I have other regex before the $ or: [] it gives me an error

Comment: I can't think I have to do a lot of nested else if to cross the various text boxes (-:

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice, it would seem that I solved it this way (let's hope nothing escapes me)

```
var search = req.query.search; //used in the main serch box
    //used as secondary textbox filters
    if(req.query.name){
     var name = req.query.name;
      }
    else if(name === undefined){name ="";}//add this
     if(req.query.email){
     var email= req.query.email;
      }
    else if(email === undefined){email="";}//add this
    
     if(req.query.city){
     var city= req.query.city;
      }
    else if(city === undefined){city="";}//add this
```

If there is a better way, so be it!