# Using ISODate with mongodb query and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am creating a string -
`queryString - {"Project": "Serenity","DateOfWalkin": {"$gte": "2022-03-01" ,"$lt": "2022-03-31"} }`

then parsing it - `queryObject = JSON.parse( queryString )`

It is parsing successfully, but when I run the query it does not give me any result.

Now when I update the same query by using ISODate for both dates, and then tried running the query in Mongo compass, it works fine.

I want to use `ISODate()` but the problem is the way I am building the `queryString` is based on different conditions from the user input, now if a particular condition is true then and only then I want to query that particular field. For other fields I am searching, which are of type "String" in my db, I am able to get the correct result, but for date I am facing this issue.

*`startDate` and `endDate` are user inputs using date picker in HTML*

**TRIAL number 1**

`queryString = queryString + ,"DateOfWalkin": {"$gte": ISODate("${startDate}")} ,"$lt": { "$date" : ISODate("${endDate}") } }`

This will give a parser error saying identifier "I" not found, hence I am not able to parse this string.

To combat this, I tried to use new Date object, tried to convert the date using `toISOString`, but it didn't work.

**TRIAL number 2**

`queryString = queryString + ,"DateOfWalkin": {"$gte": "ISODate("${startDate}")"} ,"$lt": { "$date" : "ISODate("${startDate}")" } }`

If we use double quotes for `ISODate` as well, it will solve the parser issue but Mongo query will not give any result and it is treating ISODate wrapper as a string literal.

**TRIAL number 3**

`queryString = queryString + ,"DateOfWalkin": {"$gte": "${startDate}"} ,"$lt": { "$date" : "${endDate}" } }`

Does not give result

**TRIAL number 4**

Using new Date() to get the ISODate format

Query becomes -

```
{
  Project: 'Serenity',
  DateOfWalkin: {
    '$gte': 'Tue Mar 01 2022 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)',
    '$lt': 'Thu Mar 31 2022 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)'
  }
}
```

Still it doesn't give any result

**TRIAL number 5**

Query object -

```
{
  Project: 'Serenity',
  DateOfWalkin: {
    '$gte': { '$date': '2022-03-01' },
    '$lt': { '$date': '2022-03-01' }
  }
}
```

Above doesn't give result

---

Is there any way I can store the value of `ISODate("${startDate}")` and use that variable in the main `queryString`?

Or is there a better way to compare dates when I am using the input dates as user input?

I have tried multiple approaches and kinda feeling stuck at this point.

Comment: Do you have a valid working query which you can use to query some data successfully, say from `mongo` shell? Also, what is the actual data type of the `DateOfWalkin` - a date or string field type?

Comment: data type of DateOfWalkin is date( in mongodb compass ), I have a valid query -

{Project: 'Serenity' , 'DateOfWalkin': {'$gte': ISODate("2022-03-01") ,'$lt': ISODate("2022-03-31") } }

Please note -  I am getting the values of the query from the html form , then passing these values into db.find() in node.js

Comment: See this post where a filter is built dynamically with the data from a client: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69367673/mongoose-find-function-is-there-a-value-for-in-which-would-be-true-no-matter-w/69370680#69370680 . Note that in your NodeJS application you can build a Date object using the JavaScript `Date` - you will need to do this as your date data in the database is of type Date. To compare fields they need be of same type, in a MongoDB query.

Comment: I applied the above solution which you mentioned, and it works,  I was stuck on this since forever. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why do you parse the string?

Apart from your current problem, you also open the door for [NoSQL-Injection](https://blog.websecurify.com/2014/08/hacking-nodejs-and-mongodb.html). You can compose the query object also directly like this:

```
const queryObject = {};
queryObject["Project"] = "Serenity";
queryObject["DateOfWalkin"] = { $gte: ISODate("2022-03-01"), ["$lt"]: ISODate("2022-03-31") };

const ninDates = [];
ninDates.push(ISODate("2022-03-10"));
ninDates.push(ISODate("2022-03-20"));
queryObject["DateOfWalkin"]["$nin"] = ninDates;

db.collection.find(queryObject)
```

If you really insist to parse the string, then use [ejson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejson)

```
EJSON.parse('{ "Project": "Serenity", "DateOfWalkin": { "$gte": { "$date": "2022-03-01" }, "$lt": { "$date": "2022-03-01" } } }')
```

Should give desired queryObject. Note, keys and values need to be enclosed by double-quotes (`"`)